# $last=mysqli_num_rows($result,$i,"date");

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working on switching from mysql to mysqli because I am moving to hostgator (I still have some trouble with one site I posted about earlier that I have not found a solution yet), for this one have corrected several errors by doing research and trial & error changes but there is one error that I cannot find a solution for...

WARNING: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in line 19

line 19 is...

```
$last=mysqli_result($result,$i,"date")
```

the whole code

```
<?
include("config.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM $table_u";
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$last=mysqli_result($result,$i,"date"); ?>
```

Comment: Your error is clear. Please read docs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: it is suppose to be the last update date of the database

Answer (score 0):

```
$last=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

**Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php**

Comment: I read it and I changed the code to that before and gives me 1 when it is suppose to be the last update date of the database

Comment: mysqli_num_rows will return the `number of affected rows` not `record`.

Comment: that is what I thought was the problem but Im not sure what to change it to

Comment: I just realized I accidentally changed that line from what it was before working my mysql `$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");` but it still doesnt work changing it to mysqli

Comment: this is the whole code `<? include("config.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE apr='y'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>`